# How to strengthen the floor to support a 120gallon fish tank

Tags: structural-engineering

My house was built around 1920, and has field stone foundation. The joists seem to be all 2"x8". I want to put a 120 gallon(as measured in the United States) fish tank in my home office, which will be roughly 1000lbs, plus a stand, which would be maybe another 100lbs, and the footprint of this  tank is 48"x24"x24". I  want to reinforce the floor under the tank  in the basement. I plan to place the tank along the exterior wall, about 12" away from the wall, over the first joist. To strengthen the floor, I want to use bridging to connect the joists. I will do this at every third of the  joist, for about  3-4 joists below the tank. I also plan to use two  4"x4"s, that are beneath the joists laying perpendicular to them, and are supported each by a jack post which will sit on the basement slab. I plan to use one jackpost at each third of the tank. Should this be a safe way to support the tank?

Comment: 120 g is the weight of 1/3 of a can of Coke. You'll be fine. You're on an international site.

Comment: By 120g i assume you mean “gal”...or gallons? Imperial gallons? Or ~4.5*120 litres...? Or did you mean grams?

Comment: I'm sorry I did not specify it is gallons

Comment: Are the joists perpendicular to the exterior wall ( and rest on it)? What are the centers/distance between joists ? What is the span of the joists ? I suggest actually measuring the size of the joists. I once lived in an old house ( ca 1900 , Chicago) and floor joists were a random size, I would guess something like 4 X 5.

Comment: The joists rest on the exterior wall, they are about 14" apart, and they span 5' between walls. The office is about 5'6" across. I measured the joists and they are all  2x8s, which technically are 1.5"x7.5"